# Почему компилятор выдает ошибку не инициализированной переменной?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Почему компилятор выдает ошибку, что переменная не инициализирована на `orderAssert` после выхода из цикла?

```
int i=1; boolean orderAssert; String orderNumAfter;

    while(i<=10)
    {...
        if(orderNum != orderNumAfter) {orderAssert = true;i=11;}
        else orderAssert = false;

        i++;
    }

    Assert.assertEquals(orderAssert, true); // <<-- ошибка на этой строке
```

Comment: Потому, что эта переменная может быть не инициализированная в момент обращения.

Comment: ну наверно потому что он не уверен на 100% что блок в цикле будет выполнен хотя бы один раз

Comment: что находится в месте `...`?

Comment: 1) Уверены, что не должно быть `else { orderAssert = false; i++; }?

Comment: @andy.37, а какая разница если `i++` все равно выполняется?

Comment: чтобы выйти досрочно из цикла можно использовать ключевое слово `break;`

Comment: @Grundy, там получение значения для orderNumAfter, которое не влияет на мою проблему

Comment: @DmitryFeniks, в процессе _получения значения для orderNumAfter_ может произойти исключение(exception)?

Comment: @Krom Stem, выдает ошибку прямо в коде http://screencast.com/t/SPJbxSx1qng

Comment: @KromStern, по `i=11;` я могу предположить, что в в данном коде `break;` не используется :-)

Comment: @Grundy, ошибка получения переменной может произойти только если в моем тесте не загрузится страница

Comment: @Grundy, я недавно изучаю Java, так что знаю еще не много. break; лучше =)

Comment: @DmitryFeniks, так как компилятор видит, что код выше условия может кинуть ошибку, потенциально может произойти ситуация, что до этой проверки не дойдет управление, а следовательно не присвоится значение переменной, и она останется неинициализированной, о чем и сообщает подсказка

Comment: @KromStern, никак, но тут суть именно в том, что при исключении переменная останется не инициализированной.

Comment: @KromStern, тут больше вопросы к компилятору, либо анализатору, который как раз это сообщение и показывает :-)

Comment: @KromStem, пишу код я с нуля, просто я еще учусь =)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35788/discussion-on-question-by-dmitry-feniks------).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще, очень похоже на фичу компилятора:

```
public static void testvar() {
    int a;
    boolean c = false;
    // if (c) a = 0; else a = 1;
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        if (c) a = 0; else a = 1;
        // a = 1;
    }
    System.out.println("a is " + a);
}
```

Не компилируется (`Error:(23, 38) java: variable a might not have been initialized`), причем даже если в цикле вместо `if` оставить `a = 1;`. А если раскомментировать строчку перед циклом - компилируется.

С-шный компилятор, например (у меня) не дает ворнинга на

```
int a, f=0; if (f) a = 1; a++;
```

но если убрать `if` (или поменять на `if(0)`), то уже дает)

П.С. Предложенный вариант ответа, естественно, решает проблему (и гораздо лучше с точки зрения стиля)

Answer (score 2):

Так как orderAssert может быть не инициализирован в цикле (например, если стоит break), то нужно инициализировать переменную до цикла.

Попробуй так:

```
int i = 1;
boolean orderAssert = false;
String orderNumAfter;

while (i <= 10)
{...
    if (orderNum != orderNumAfter) {
        orderAssert = true;
        i = 11;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: мне нужно вынести значение orderAssert из цикла